# I am trying to format one specific validation message out of several others

Tags: css, margin

```css
span.k-widget.k-tooltip-validation {
   text-align: right;
   float: right;
   font-size: 12px;
   padding: 0;
   background: none;
   border: none;
   box-shadow: none;
   color: red;
}
```

```html
<li>
    <label for="help">Help</label>
    <input type="text" id="help" name="help" 
     placeholder="Enter your question"required 
     validationMessage="This field is required.">
    <span class="k-invalid-msg"></span>  
</li>     

<li>
    <label for="isactive" class="req">Active? </label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="status" required 
     validationMessage="This field is required.">No
</li>
```

I am using Kendo validator to create a custom validation message. It says "this field is required" whenever the input is invalid. While the first label is a text-input, the 2nd label "isactive" is a checkbox. I am trying to format the validation message for "isactive" in CSS but I don't know how to access that specific message without changing all the other validation messages.

Can someone please give me an example for how I can change the margin-top ONLY for the validation msg for "isactive" in CSS?

Comment: did you tired `label[for=isactive]
{
    /* ...definitions here... */
}`